# Porting from 32-bit to 64-bit - any alternative to -Wp64 switch?

Tags: visual-studio, 32bit-64bit

I'm porting my 32-bit (Win32) application to 64-bit using VS 2012.
I read on MSDN that -Wp64 switch helps with porting by generating warnings on pointer trunction et al so we can address them during the compilation phase before they become an issue at run-time.
However, MSDN as well as the compiler output (in the output window) says that this option has been deprecated and in fact won't even be supported by later Visual Studio releases.
I want to know if there's a better alternative to -Wp64 that will be supported by future Visual Studio versions too.

Comment: It was deprecated at VS2010 and removed at VS2013 because there is now a better way.  Target x64 and compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This article](https://www.viva64.com/en/a/0021/) is to answer some questions related to safe port of C/C++ code on 64-bit systems. The article is written as an answer to the topic often discussed on forums and related to the use of /Wp64 key.

Try PVS-Studio [64-bit Rules Set](https://www.viva64.com/en/w/#64CPP) for detect 64-bit issues (support Visual Studio 2010-2017). Also I am recommend read [this](https://www.viva64.com/en/l/full/): the course will consider all steps in creating a new safe 64-bit application, or migrating the existing 32-bit code to a 64-bit system.

Comment: thanks a ton Andrey. Also thanks for sharing the useful links.